# Dynamic paper form generation

Tags: .net, winforms, printing

Currently, I've got an application that needs to fill out a printable form with data.  clients send me a form and I create a digital version of it. There are tons of these forms and I often need to customize them and add additional fields, etc for my clients, so they should be really simple to create and modify.

I've got a system in place, but it's really cumbersome and problematic.  what are some well put together applications or libraries that can be used for this sort of thing?

**Edit:** some more specifics:

- the application is mostly windows forms
- these forms need to be dynamically generated on client machines, so i'd prefer to stay away from anything that requires a large redist package (i.e. crystal reports).

Answer (score 1):

That's what [Office InfoPath](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath/) was designed to do.  It's got an automation interface, like any Office product, easily usable from a .NET program.  Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath namespace.  Microsoft takes care of the redist :)

Comment: and 2010 version of InfoPath client is free.

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of solutions and a ton of money spent for this problem I've personally done the following

- SQL Reporting
- Crystal Reports
- Custom outputs.
- Word Automation
- Excel Automation
- XML to XSL to different outputs
- XML to Adobe FrameMaker

Perhaps if you gave more specifics one could give a more specific answer

Comment: Added a couple more details.  What do you mean by "outputs" in the above list?  I'm not sure I understand #s 3 and 6.